# How can I wrap the height of the ListView.builder with a Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen using `ListView.builder`.

I gave the background of the list a light color with `Container` and I gaved `BorderRadius.circular` it.
[Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLuJ.gif). I want this background to wrap the list. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgHz8.jpg).
Curves must to be at the beginning and end of the list.

I've tried:
I gave a `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the `ListView.builder`. I wrapped the first `Container` with a `SingleChildScrollView`. Although background continues below I must to give a height. But I don't know how long the list will be. So that method did not work.

What am I missing?

Full code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.green,
        primaryColor: Colors.green,
        accentColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: ListScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hello"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
              color: Colors.white38,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/330px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg",
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              "${index + 1}. Tree",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        height: 0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a screenshot of your expected result

Comment: Okay I edited with an image.

Comment: Wrap your padding border in first and last list item, first with topleft and topright and top padding, last item with bottomleft and bottomright and bottom padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way tried in the question was correct. It is only necessary to add `shrinkWrap: true`  to the `ListView.builder()`.

It will look like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                color: Colors.white38,
              ),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(//builder);
                },
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: list.length,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` widget is simply the stationary window on the screen that the *child widgets* scroll through. In order to achieve the desired effect, you need to use `BorderRadius.only` to round the correct corners of the first and last children of the `ListView`.

Comment: Yes. I can do as you say. But I want to do this when I don't know the number of list items. That's why I used `ListView.builder` .

Comment: But you have to pass the `itemCount` to `ListView.builder`.

Comment: `itemCount: list.length`

Comment: Right. My point is, you have to know the length of the list. Therefore, it should be no issue to take the approach I am recommending. Which is actually the only way to get what you want as you really want to shape the `ListTile`s rather than the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct path here

> I've tried: I gave a physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to the ListView.builder. I wrapped the first Container with a SingleChildScrollView. Although background continues below I must to give a height. But I don't know how long the list will be. So that method did not work.

in addition this this,

what you are missing here is using `Expanded` widget using expanding widget let the child expand as much as it want try this

```
 Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Expanding(
            child:Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
              color: Colors.white38,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
              // your ListView.builder code here with neverScrollablePhysics
            ),
          ),
        ))
```

remember to wrap this all a `singleChildScrollView()` and maybe use a Column() too

Comment: Yes. I tried wrapping `Container` with a `Expand`.  There is an  `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. `  error. Obviously I didn't understand where to use `Column()`